# Email send through nodemailer goes into spam for gmail

Tags: node.js, gmail, nodemailer, email-spam

I am sending email through nodemailer it goes into inbox of gmail if i run from local server but goes into spam of gmail if i run script from microsoft azure server.
following is my script

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var EmailTemplates = require('swig-email-templates');
var smtpConfig =  {
        service: 'smtp.office365.com',
        host: 'smtp.office365.com',
        port: 587,
        starttls: {
            enable: true
        },
        secureConnection: true,
        auth: {
            user: 'xxxxx@yyyy.com',
            pass: 'zzzzzz'
        }
    }

var templates = new EmailTemplates();  
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);   

var context = {
  username:'Rajesh',
  email:'xxxxx@gmail.com',
  link : 'www.google.co.in'
};

templates.render('activate_email.html', context, function(err, html,text, subject) {    

  transporter.sendMail({
    from: '"Product Name" <no-reply@xxxxx.com>', // sender address
    to: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
      subject: 'Account activation',
      html: html,
      text:text    
  });    
});
```

Comment: I followed the email format provided in this answer and it stopped marking my email as spam: https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-send-a-password-email-verification-link-using-NodeJS-1/answer/Arielle-Baldwynn?ch=99&share=8654a1c8&srid=uBOYG

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The truth is there is no simple one line solutions for your problem :) There are numerous reasons why this can happen, and here are some of them:

- Your host is marked as a spam - this happens if you have not verified your e-mail or you are sending too much e-mails from the same host. Shared hosting is commonly marked as such, and therefore mail server will regularly mark them as a spam
- Your `from` field is different than the one you're allowed to use - as I see you're using smtp, there are strict rules for the mail you can send. Of course you can always send e-mail from `mark@facebook.com`, but since your SMTP's host is **not** facebook.com, your e-mail will pretty sure marked as spam
- You can sign your e-mail in many various mails, assuring the servers that this e-mail is send from you and it has proper signature. Check online for the ways to do so.
- While developing you have sent numerous alike e-mails - sending the very same "test" e-mail is a common reason for your e-mails to get blacklisted
- There are emojis in your subject - that is not a 100% reason, but servers are often marking such e-mails as spams, especially in other fields (like `from`)

Unfortunately as I said there is no one real reason, there could be many of them. I hope this helps at least a little :)

Comment: i'm on heroku using gmail everything is correct (the from is the same as my gmail account no emoji etc..) is there a solution ?

Comment: I had this problem because of the smiley face.

Answer (score 9):

in my case i needed to specify the form, the from need to be = to user mail

```
auth: {
  user: "xxx@yyy.com",
  pass: "password",
      }, 
from: xxx@yyy.com,
```

Answer (score 6):

Please get rid of the  and try sending it again. I read in a article once that email clients don't like those icons because a lot of spammers are using them.

Try sending it to multiple gmail accounts. Other than that there's nothing wrong with the code. If you're on a shared hosting or local host it could also go into the junk folder. In that case you would have to look into sending the emails from a different IP, preferred in the same country as where you will send the emails to.

But first try to remove that icon!

PS. I would make this answer as a comment but I can't due to low rep.

Comment: I removed but still problem. but if I removed link from email then its working.So what could be solution to link issue

Comment: the problem could be the domain it's pointing to or the text in the <a>. Try with different domain, like link to google.com or something. And use text "google" try if that works.

Answer (score 5):

For those who are still struggling with this problem. I suggest the following.

1. Make sure you add `from` field that matches with `auth.user`

```
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
    secureConnection: false,
    port: 587,
    tls: {
      ciphers: "SSLv3",
    },
    auth: {
      user: <YOUR_EMAIL_ACCOUNT>,
      pass: <YOUR_EMAIL_PASSWORD>,
    },
    from: <YOUR_EMAIL_ACCOUNT>,
  });
```

2. Add `text` field describing your intent for the email in `options` payload

```
  const mailOptions = {
    from: `myCompany <mycompanyemail@gmail.com>`,
    to: "recipient@gmail.com",
    subject: "[MYCOMPANY] YOUR EMAIL VERIFICATION",
    text: "Hello. This email is for your email verification.",
    html: <h1>Hello</h1>,
  };
```

3. If #1 or #2 doesn't solve your problem. Try using [test-mailer](https://www.mail-tester.com/) and send email to their provided test email address. It will show you where your vulnerabilities are especially the part where you have to setup `SPF`, `DKIM`, and `DMARC.`
4. If you are using a custom domain setup `SPF`, `DKIM`, `DMARC` following this [article](https://medium.com/@jakebarn/why-your-gsuite-emails-are-going-to-spam-b231caf93355).

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party..

Try adding both HTML and Text Versions both in your emailConfig as below. That way the email will land up in the inbox. It worked for me.

```
var emailOptions = {
from: 'cxxxxxkxxxxx@xxxxx.com',
to: 'xxxx@xxxxxx.com',
cc:'sxxxxxxsh@xxxx.com, xxxa@xxx.com, aaaxxxx@xxxx.com',
    bcc:'xxxxx.wrxxxk@xxxx.com',
    subject: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    /* Adding HTML and Text Version, so the email will not land up in the Spam folder */
    html: 'Hello Team! <br><br>Please find attached...<br><br>Thanks,<br>XXXXX',
    text: 'Hello Team! <br><br>Please find attached...<br><br>Thanks,<br>XXXXX',
    attachments: [{
        // file on disk as an attachment, concatenating the file extension separately since NODE is not renaming the file properly with fs.renameSync
        filename: finalFileNameWithoutExt + '.xlsx',
        path: reportsLocationPathWithYearMonth + finalFileNameWithoutExt + '.xlsx' // stream this file
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

used to have that error because i actually left out the from in the transporter thinking it was in the optionsMail so i didn't have to add twice but once i added it to the transporter it worked

Answer (score -3):

HTML goes to junk, plain text doesn't

Comment: Text also goes to junk, not for gmail accounts though, but for other mail accounts

Comment: This isn't necessarily true.