# sending email through my vue.js web application on the inbox folder instead of the spam folder with a different email

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, email, nodemailer

I am very new to email integration for web applications so please bear with me in this situation...

I am working on a site for a startup company and I currently have a vue.js front end app using the webpack template which contains a contact form for clients to contact the company. I also have a node.js back end application which receives the data from the front end application using websocket which I intend to use to send emails with the clients information to the startup company. My aim is to be able to send emails without using the transporter email address , but use the email address in the from: object instead. I would also like to make sure my email doesnt appear in the spam folder.

In this example I tried using nodemailer but the email does not show the client s'email and the email appears in the junk folder.

my front end vue.js application:

```
<template>
    <main id="fullpage">
        <b-form @submit.prevent="validateForm($event)" id="contactForm" autocomplete="off" 
        method="post">
            <section class="section contactForm">   
                <b-form-row>
                    <h1>{{clientMsg}}</h1>
                </b-form-row>
                <b-form-row>
                    <b-col>
                        <input type="radio" name="client" value="individual" @click="IndvClient"> <label for="individual">an individual?</label>
                    </b-col>
                    <b-col>
                        <input type="radio" name="client" value="company" @click="CorporateClient" > <label for="company">a company?</label>
                    </b-col>
                    <b-col cols="12">
                        <a class="steps text-right next" :href="sectionLinks.emailLink">Next</a>
                    </b-col>
                </b-form-row>
            </section>
            <section class="section contactForm">
                <b-row no-gutters>      
                    <b-col>
                        <input type="email" id="usrEmail" placeholder="Email address..." class="text-center" 
                        :pattern="emailValidation" required v-model="email" @mouseout="isValidEmail($event)" autocomplete="off">
                    </b-col>
                </b-row>
                <b-row no-gutters>
                    <b-col cols="6">
                        <a href="#clientType" class="steps text-left">Previous</a>
                    </b-col>
                    <b-col cols="6">
                        <a class="steps text-right next" :href="sectionLinks.nameLink">Next</a>
                    </b-col>
                </b-row>
            </section>
            <section class="section contactForm">
                    <input type="text" name="usrName" id="usrName" placeholder="Name..." class="text-center"
                    required :pattern="textValidation" v-model="name" @mouseout="isValidName($event)" autocomplete="off">
                    <b-row no-gutters>
                        <b-col cols="6">
                            <a href="#email" class="steps text-left">Previous</a>
                        </b-col>
                        <b-col cols="6">
                            <a class="steps text-right next" :href="sectionLinks.titleLink">Next</a>
                        </b-col>
                    </b-row>
            </section>
            <section class="section contactForm">
                    <input type="text" name="msgTitle" id="msgTitle" placeholder="Title of the message..." 
                    class="text-center" v-model="messageTitle" required :pattern="textValidation"
                    @mouseout="isValidTitle($event)" autocomplete="off">
                    <b-row no-gutters>
                        <b-col cols="6">
                            <a href="#name" class="steps text-left">Previous</a>
                        </b-col>
                        <b-col cols="6">
                            <a class="steps text-right next" :href="sectionLinks.msgLink" >Next</a>
                        </b-col>
                    </b-row>
            </section>
            <section class="section contactForm">
                <b-row no-gutters>
                    <b-col cols="12">
                        <textarea name="" id="msgContent" cols="100" rows="7" 
                        placeholder="Message..." v-model="message" required 
                        @mouseout="isValidMsg($event)"></textarea>
                    </b-col>
                </b-row>
                <b-row no-gutters>
                    <b-col cols="6">
                        <a href="#title" class="steps text-left">Previous</a>
                    </b-col>
                    <b-col cols="6">
                        <a class="steps text-right next" :href="sectionLinks.msgSummaryLink">Next</a>
                    </b-col>
                </b-row>  
            </section>
            <section class="section contactForm formSummary">
                    <ul class="prevFormLinks">
                        <li v-for="section in previousLinks">
                            <a :href="section.link">{{section.name}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <b-form-row>
                        <p>{{clientMsg}}</p>
                    </b-form-row>
                    <b-form-row>
                        <b-col>
                            <input type="radio" name="userClient" value="individual"> <label for="individual">an individual?</label>
                        </b-col>
                        <b-col>
                            <input type="radio" name="userClient" value="company"> <label for="company">a company?</label>
                        </b-col>
                    </b-form-row>
                    <b-form-row>
                        <b-col>
                            <h2>Your email:</h2>
                        </b-col>
                        <b-col>
                            <p>{{email}}</p>
                        </b-col>
                    </b-form-row>
                    <b-form-row>
                        <b-col>
                            <h2>Name:</h2>
                        </b-col>
                        <b-col>
                            <p>{{name}}</p>
                        </b-col>
                    </b-form-row>
                    <b-form-row>
                        <b-col>
                            <h4>Title of the message:</h4>
                        </b-col>
                        <b-col>      
                            <p>{{messageTitle}}</p>
                        </b-col>
                    </b-form-row>
                    <b-form-row>
                        <b-col cols="5" id="msgSummary">
                            <p>{{message}}</p>
                        </b-col>
                    </b-form-row>
                    <b-form-row>
                        <b-col cols="12">
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
                        </b-col>
                    </b-form-row>
            </section>
        </b-form>  
    </main>
</template>
<script>
import fullpage from 'fullpage.js'
import $ from "jquery"
/** 
    Make sure you can then send an email
    Replace the jQuery animations with anime.js or another way of animating.
    There are no previous buttons for the summary section.
    */
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
                "clientMsg":this.$store.state.contact.TypeOfClientMsg,
                "name":"",
                "email":"",
                "messageTitle":"",
                "message":"",
                "emailValidation":"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$",
                "textValidation":"[a-zA-Z ]+",
                "sectionLinks":{
                    "clientLink":"#clientType",
                    "emailLink":"#email",
                    "nameLink": "#name",
                    "titleLink":"#title",
                    "msgLink":"#message",
                    "msgSummaryLink":"#messageSummary"
                },
                "previousLinks":[
                    {
                        "link":"#clientType",
                        "name":"Client"
                    },
                    {
                        "link":"#email",
                        "name":"Email"
                    },
                    {
                        "link":"#name",
                        "name":"Name"
                    },
                    {
                        "link":"#title",
                        "name":"Title"
                    },
                    {
                        "link":"#message",
                        "name":"Message"
                    }
                ],
                "companyEmail":"salay777@hotmail.co.uk"
            }
        },
        methods:{
            IndvClient:function(){
                    let ind = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="individual"]');
                    let company = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="company"]'),
                    goToEmail = document.querySelector('a[href="#email"]');
                    (ind[0].checked == true)? ind[1].checked = true : ind[1].checked = false;
                    $(goToEmail).fadeIn();
            },
            CorporateClient:function(){
                    let ind = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="individual"]');
                    let company = document.querySelectorAll('input[value="company"]'),
                    goToEmail = document.querySelector('a[href="#email"]');
                    (company[0].checked == true)? company[1].checked = true : company[1].checked = false;
                    $(goToEmail).fadeIn();
            },
            isValidEmail:function(e){
                let goToName = document.querySelector('a[href="#name"]');
                (e.target.checkValidity())? $(goToName).fadeIn() : $(goToName).fadeOut();
            },
            isValidName:function(e){
               let goToTitle = document.querySelector('a[href="#title"]');
               (e.target.checkValidity())? $(goToTitle).fadeIn() : $(goToTitle).fadeOut();
            },
            isValidTitle:function(e){
                let goToMsg = document.querySelector('a[href="#message"]');
                (e.target.checkValidity())? $(goToMsg).fadeIn() : $(goToMsg).fadeOut();
            },
            isValidMsg:function(e){
                let goToSummary = document.querySelector('a[href="#messageSummary"]');
                (e.target.checkValidity())? $(goToSummary).fadeIn() : $(goToSummary).fadeOut();
            },
            validateForm:function(e){
                let idvClient = document.querySelector('input[value="individual"]'),
                corporateClient = document.querySelector('input[value="company"]'),
                usrEmail = document.getElementById('usrEmail'), usrName = document.
                getElementById('usrName'), msgTitle = document.getElementById('msgTitle'),
                msgContent = document.getElementById('msgContent'), 
                socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000/');


                if(idvClient.checked !== corporateClient.checked){
                    console.log('client has been checked');
                    if(usrEmail.checkValidity() == false || usrName.checkValidity() == false ||
                        msgTitle.checkValidity() == false || msgContent.checkValidity() == false){
                            e.preventDefault();
                        } else {
                            let email = {
                                    client :"",
                                    email: this.email,
                                    name: this.name,
                                    title: this.messageTitle,
                                    message: this.message
                            };
                            if(idvClient.checked){
                                email.client = "[IDV]";
                            }
                            if(corporateClient.checked){
                                email.client = "[CO]";
                            }

                            socket.emit('email',email);
                            alert('submitted!');
                        }
                } else {
                    console.log('you need to select a client type');
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        },
        mounted(){
                let idvClient = document.querySelector('input[value="individual"]'),
                corporateClient = document.querySelector('input[value="company"]'),
                goToEmail = document.querySelector('a[href="#email"]'), form =
                document.querySelector('form');

                form.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');

                if(idvClient.checked == corporateClient.checked){
                    goToEmail.style.display = 'none';
                }
        }
    };
</script>
<style>

html body #fullpage {
    background-color:#383838 !important; 
    background-image: none !important;
}

html, body,#fullpage {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
 .fp-tableCell{
  text-align:center;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center; 
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;

}

 .contactDetails .row {
   margin:0px;
 }

.contactForm .form-row {
  min-width:500px;
  justify-content:center;
}

.contactForm .form-row a, .contactForm .row a {
    margin: 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f4f4f4;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 100;
    transition: color .5s, font-size .2s;
}

.contactForm .form-row a:hover, .contactForm .row a:hover {
    color:orange;
    font-size:40px;
}

#menu {
    display: none !important;
}

button {
    margin-top:20px;
}

h1, h2, h3 , h4 {
    font-weight:100;
}

.next {
    display: none;
}

#msgSummary {
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align:left;
}

.formSummary, .formSummary h2 , .formSummary h4, 
.formSummary p {
    text-align:left !important;
}

.prevFormLinks {
    position:absolute;
    left:30px;
    text-align:left;
    margin:0px !important;
    padding:0px;
    color:white !important;
}

.prevFormLinks a {
    font-size:20px !important;
    margin:0px!important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white !important;
    font-weight:100;
    transition: font-size .25s, color 2s;
}

.prevFormLinks a:hover {
    font-size: 25px !important;
    color: orange !important;
}
</style>
```

my email module for my back end application:

let emailModule = (function(){
    let nodemailer = require('nodemailer'), mailOptions = {from:'', to:'', subject:'', text:''};

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service : 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user:'projectgorillatransporter@gmail.com',
        pass'*******'
    }
});

let setMailOptions = (from, to, subject, text)=>{
   return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        mailOptions.from = from;
        mailOptions.to = to;
        mailOptions.subject = subject;
        mailOptions.text = text;

        console.log(mailOptions);
        resolve(mailOptions);
        reject(Error('the mailOPtions object was not created'));
   });
};

let sendEmail = (mailOptions)=>{
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info)=>{
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
          }
    });
}

    return {
        send : sendEmail,
        setMailOptions : setMailOptions
    }
})(); // end of the email module

module.exports = emailModule;
```

my node.js server in charge of handling data:

```
let express = require('express'), app = express(), path = require('path'),
socket = require('socket.io'), emailModule = require('./email.js');

let server = app.listen(5000, ()=>{
    console.log('listening to requests...');
});


let io = socket(server);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

io.on('connection', (socket)=>{
    console.log('made a connection!');

    socket.on('email', (data)=>{
        /**
         * Here you need to set your email options which includes the clients email, destination email,
         * subject and the text (the email content).
         */
        emailModule.setMailOptions(data.email,'salay777@hotmail.co.uk', data.client + ' ' + '(' +
        data.name + ')' + ' ' + data.title, data.message).then((mailOpts)=>{
            emailModule.send(mailOpts);
            console.log('email has been sent!');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I have changed my question as requested, It would help if you would remove the off topic sign on my question please.

Comment: You're trying to spoof the sender email address, which is exactly the sort of thing that will cause your messages to be classified as spam. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608635/email-send-through-nodemailer-goes-into-spam-for-gmail

Answer (score 0):

There is email-templates and sendmail, though nodemailer is very easy. Have you taken a look at either of the first two packages?

Comment: no I havent looked at email-templates or sendmail, but was I right in saying that nodemailer requires my own email information to send emails? I am trying to make sure the clients can contact the company via the form on the website like a typical contact form you would see in other companies.

Comment: Not necessarily your own email, but nodemailer requires a smtp mail server and valid credentials to use. You could accomplish this with any of those packages, its more personal preference than anything.

Comment: and thanks for the help by the way I am looking into those two packages at the moment.

Comment: Hi, I tried nodemailer once again, it did work hut as I initially suspected, the email was from the email I put my credentials for and it appeared in the junk folder.

Comment: I'm not following what the issue is exactly. The package sounds like it is working as designed.